# Python Client Server with Docker - Connection refused

Tags: python, docker, sockets, client-server

I'm trying to develop a simple client/server application in python.

The client is running in a Docker container whereas the server is running directly on the host machine.

Here is the code of the client:

```py
import socket

def main():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8888))
    print (Connected to server)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and here is the code of the server:

```py
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 8888

print ("Serving on ", PORT)

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print('Connected by', addr)
```

I have the following error:

```
  File "./main.py", line 5, in main
    s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8888))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

If I run this client outside a container (directly on host machine), i can connect. But I have this error when I run it in a container.

PS: It's not pure Docker container but an IoT Edge module

Do you know what is the problem ?
Thanks

Comment: In the server, `HOST` must be the special "all interfaces" address 0.0.0.0, or else it will be unreachable from outside the container.  In the client, you need to give the container name of the server as the hostname, 127.0.0.1 is "this container".  Both need to be on the same Docker network.

Answer (score 2):

first `s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8888))` in the container means to connect to the container itself not the host, to make that works you should run your `Container` with `--network=host`

second Option is to supply your `host` IP address to the client:

```
s.connect(('HOST_ROUTABLE_IP_ADDRESS', 8888))
```

Comment: This will probably work, but it [removes any kind of network isolation](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/) from the docker container, which is potentially a huge security risk.

Comment: the server is running on `localhost`not in a container therefor I suggest this solution

Comment: ha, true. I probably wrote a little soon, but it's good to know anyway.

Comment: Ok thanks I will try this. And in the case the server is also running in a container (on the same host machine), do I need to do something particular or can I use localhost in this case? Thanks

Comment: no you should configure networking between them and connect using `container` name `s.connect(('container_name', 8888))`

Comment: @LinPy Spend hours searching for a solution and finally I found it in your comment. Thanks a bunch!